# How to fix undefined symbol: omp_get_max_threads?

Tags: tensorflow, openmp

I configure TF 2.0.0 so as to create this .tf_configure.bazelrc:

```
build --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH="/N/slate/steige/dl_test/Python-3.7.6/bin/python"
build --action_env PYTHON_LIB_PATH="/N/soft/rhel7/deeplearning/Python-3.6.8/pytorch/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/"
build --python_path="/N/slate/steige/dl_test/Python-3.7.6/bin/python"
build --action_env PYTHONPATH="/N/soft/rhel7/deeplearning/Python-3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/N/soft/rhel7/deeplearning/Python-3.6.8/pytorch/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/"
build:xla --define with_xla_support=true
build --config=xla
build --config=tensorrt
build --action_env TF_CUDA_VERSION="10"
build --action_env TF_CUDNN_VERSION="7"
build --action_env TF_TENSORRT_VERSION="5"
build --action_env TF_NCCL_VERSION=""
build --action_env TF_CUDA_PATHS="/N/slate/steige/dl_test/gcc-7.4.0/lib64,/N/soft/rhel7/cuda/10.0,/N/soft/rhel7/cuda/10.0/lib64,/N/soft/rhel7/cuda/10.0/include/,/N/soft/rhel7/cuda/10.
0/bin,/N/slate/steige/dl_test/TensorRT-5.1.5.0/include,/N/slate/steige/dl_test/TensorRT-5.1.5.0/lib,/N/slate/steige/dl_test/Python-3.7.6/cuda/include,/N/slate/steige/dl_test/Python-3.
7.6/cuda/lib64"
build --action_env CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH="/N/soft/rhel7/cuda/10.0"
build --action_env TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES="6.0,7.0"
build --action_env LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/N/slate/steige/dl_test/TensorRT-5.1.5.0/lib:/N/slate/steige/dl_test/gcc-7.4.0/lib:/N/slate/steige/dl_test/gcc-7.4.0/lib64:/N/slate/steige/dl_test/
Python-3.7.6/cuda/lib64:CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY:/N/soft/rhel7/deeplearning/cuda/lib64:/N/soft/rhel7/deeplearning/Python-3.6.8/lib:/N/soft/rhel7/deeplearning/Python-3.6.8/pytorch/torch/lib
64:/N/soft/rhel7/deeplearning/Python-3.6.8/pytorch/torch/lib:/N/soft/rhel7/cuda/10.0/lib64:/N/soft/rhel7/perl/gnu/5.24.1/lib"
build --action_env GCC_HOST_COMPILER_PATH="/N/slate/steige/dl_test/gcc-7.4.0/bin/gcc"
build --config=cuda
build:opt --copt=-Wno-sign-compare
build:opt --copt=-fno-canonical-system-headers
build:opt --copt=-mavx
build:opt --copt=-mavx2
build:opt --copt=-mfma
build:opt --copt=-msse4.1
build:opt --copt=-msse4.2
build:opt --copt=-O3
build:opt --copt=-fopenmp
build:opt --copt=-lgomp
build:opt --host_copt=-march=native
build:opt --define with_default_optimizations=true
test --flaky_test_attempts=3
test --test_size_filters=small,medium
test --test_tag_filters=-benchmark-test,-no_oss,-oss_serial
test --build_tag_filters=-benchmark-test,-no_oss
test --test_tag_filters=-gpu
test --build_tag_filters=-gpu
build --action_env TF_CONFIGURE_IOS="0"
```

I then attempt to use it via:
import tensorflow as tf
print("tensorflow: ",tf.**version**)

This gives me the following:

```
python ttt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/N/slate/steige/dl_test/Python-3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/N/slate/steige/dl_test/Python-3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/N/slate/steige/dl_test/Python-3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/N/slate/steige/dl_test/Python-3.7.6/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/N/slate/steige/dl_test/Python-3.7.6/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /N/slate/steige/dl_test/Python-3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: omp_get_max_threads
```

I have used the suggested --copt flags to enable OpenMP. I verify the path to the missing library (libgomp.so) is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is known to the configuration and that libgomp.so is, in fact in /N/slate/steige/dl_test/gcc-7.4.0/lib64.

My gcc is not installed in a "standard" location but it looks to me like there is no
working way to tell TF where to find the missing dependencies.

Moving gcc is not an option for me, the system must support multiple, simultaneous versions
of gcc.

I do not know how to go about fixing this but it seems like a pretty serious problem.
I see similar behavior in TF 2.1 where it expects libstdc++.so to be located in /lib64
Any help or a fix would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

LD_PRELOAD= python ttt.py
is the workaround.

This really needs to be fixed, deployment on major systems is not going to happen until it is fixed.

Comment: My `LD_PRELOAD` was empty already and this doesn't fix my case.